# Strange Diagonal Lines on Chrome Browser

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have recently noticed some websites have strange diagonal lines across the page.  See this screencast for visual explanation:

https://www.screencast.com/t/lSpaBatAZQ

As you can see they are fixed by going into the chrome inspector and disabling the background-color class in the CSS.

I have tried everything on how to fix this.  It only happens on chrome but does not happen on all sites and does not happen on my other computer when visiting the same websites.

I've reset chrome, cleared cache, disabled plugins, completely reinstalled.  Nothing has fixed this issue other than disabling background-color.

Running latest chrome, Windows 10

Comment: It looks like some of the inner `divs` have background-image, not `body` or `html`. Could you provide a link?

Comment: This question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946156/strange-diagonal-lines-in-chrome-chromium-bug

Answer (score 4):

Quote from another user:

"It's not with hardware acceleration per se, but rather with MSAA. If you set GPU Rasterization MSAA to 0 (chrome://flags) the issue disappears, while keeping hardware acceleration on :)"

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem. Hardware Acceleration in the Chrome Settings was the cause.  Using NVidia drivers seems to be a conflict.